# A squared integrals

Tags: integration, brownian-motion, standard-deviation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Is it true that 
$$
\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(u)du\right)^{2}=\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(u)du\right)\cdot\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(v)dv\right)=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t}f(u)f(v)dudv\;?
$$
I have tried to prove it with Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality,
but I couldn't. The original problem is to determine 
$$
\mathbb{D}^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{t}W(s)ds\right)
$$
 where $W(t)$ is a Wiener process. I know 
$$
\mathbb{D}^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{t}W(s)ds\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\int_{0}^{t}W(s)ds\right)^{2}\right)-\underbrace{\mathbb{E}^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{t}W(s)ds\right)}_{0}=\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\int_{0}^{t}W(s)ds\right)\cdot\left(\int_{0}^{t}W(u)du\right)\right).
$$
 Our teacher has written it is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\int_{0}^{t}W(s)ds\right)\cdot\left(\int_{0}^{t}W(u)du\right)\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t}W(s)W(u)duds\right),
$$
 but I don't really see why it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pull out a constant from an integral.

$\displaystyle \int_0^t \alpha f(u)du=\alpha \int_0^t f(u)du\quad$ for $\quad\displaystyle\alpha=\int_0^t f(v)dv$.

This is because $t$ is independent from $u,v$ so both integrals are just constants in regard to the other.

This would not be true, if the bound was not independent, see this result:

- [Is the integral squared equal to two times the integral from $a$ to $b$ and from $x$ to $b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2230008/399263)