# Product of Lebesgue integrals is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm attempting to show the following: If $f:[0,1] \to (0,\infty)$ is measurable, then $$ \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} \,dx≥1$$

My first inclination is to use something like Fubini or Tonelli to turn the product into a single integral, but I'm not sure I can apply either theorem here.

Comment: since each integral is a constant for the other you can always put the constant  inside and get $\iint \frac{f(x)}{f(y)}\mathop{dx}\mathop{dy}$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3616223/399263 But I'm not sure this would help though.

Comment: Also, Jensen's inequality immediately gives the result.

Comment: @DanielFischer In order to use Jensen's inequality doesn't $f$ need to be integrable? I'm having trouble seeing if it is.

Comment: If it isn't, then we have a product $+\infty \cdot \text{ strictly positive}$. Yes, we need to treat that separately. (We can extend Jensen's inequality to also work for this, but that would be significantly more work than reasonable. We would have to show it's strict when the integral is infinite, since $+\infty\cdot 0$ doesn't cut it here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, we have
$$ 1=\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{\sqrt{f(x)}}dx\right)^2\leqslant\left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_0^1\frac{dx}{f(x)}\right) $$

Comment: And one (or both) of the integrals on the right could have value $+\infty$.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why $f$ and $1/f$ are integrable. I know this is a requirement for using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @Newman No, Cauchy-Schwarz (and Hölder's inequality) don't require integrability. If one of the functions isn't integrable and the other function isn't equal to $0$ (a.e.), then the right hand side is $+\infty$ and the inequality trivially holds. If the other function is $0$ (a.e.), then the left hand side is $0$ and the inequality trivially holds.

Comment: @DanielFischer I suppose the issue I'm having is in the second case you mention. If  $f=0$ a.e., then isn't the LHS undefined as then we have $0/0$?

Comment: @Newman It would be, but this case is ruled out by the assumption $f \colon [0,1] \to (0,+\infty)$. We have $0 < f(x) < +\infty$ for all $x$.